# How do I update a partial view separate from the partial view I posted?

Tags: c#, model, asp.net-mvc-5, controller, partial-views

Suppose I have two ViewModels, A and B.

```
public class ViewModel_A {...};
public class ViewModel_B {...};
```

Each of these view models has their own GET and POST functions, corresponding to that ViewModel's partial view. These are both part of a single, larger view.

VIEW

```
<body>
     <div id="PartialView_A">
          @{Html.RenderAction("PartialView_A");}
     </div>

     <div id="PartialView_B">
          @{Html.RenderAction("PartialView_B");}
     </div>
</body>
```

MODELS

```
//GET  View Model A
public ActionResult PartialView_A() {...}

//POST View Model A
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialView_A(ViewModel_A) {

     //CODE - Update Model A
     //CODE - Update Model B
     //CODE - Send a callback of some sort to the client?
     return View("partial_viewA", ViewModel_A);

}

//GET  View Model B
public ActionResult PartialView_B() {...}

//POST View Model B
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialView_B(ViewModel_B) {
     return View("partial_viewB", ViewModel_B);
}
```

The data within ViewModel B needs to be updated depending upon the data within ViewModel A. The reverse is not true. Therefore, both Partial View A and Partial View B must be updated when ViewModel A is POST-ed to the server.

In order to keep my view and code more modular and flexible, as well as reduce consumed bandwidth, I have elected to not have ViewModel B set within ViewModel A.

Is there a way for server to tell the client to call the POST function for Partial View B, with the server providing the client with the updated ViewModel B?

Comment: How are you calling the post function...? what do you use for your frontend? I would imagine that you can handle it there.

Comment: @TSmith, I've added the main view to the question. For my project, I intend to call the post a specific partial view whenever items within that partial view are clicked, via a jQuery event. I had intentionally left the method of calling the post vague, as I thought *how* the post is called is irrelevant as long as the model is posted. Is that not true?

Comment: In my opinion, depending on how your event handler is coded, you could just call functions to "refresh" the partial views within the handler. You said that they're click events so the button that updates A could also update B within the same event handler